# Why does my view's coordinates systems randomly mess up?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, coordinates

I have a game with a uiview that takes up the entire screen and moves upwards every 5 seconds, until the game ends.

This works great, the uiview moves fine, but when I reset the game and I try to move the uiview back to its original location it seems to be about 40 pixels off. This is what I do when the game ends:

```
self.myView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,586); // the iphone 5 screen is 586 points long.
```

However, the views y is really some where like 360, not 320; why would this happen?

Incidentally, I have those weird constraint things off because I can't move the uiview with them on.

Comment: COuld you post more code so I can see whats happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because I unchecked all my struts and springs and I unchecked 'use auto layout' in the file inspector